# Commit in git only if tests pass

Tags: python, unit-testing, git, githooks

I've recently started using git, and also begun unit testing (using Python's `unittest` module). I'd like to run my tests each time I commit, and only commit if they pass.

I'm guessing I need to use `pre-commit` in `/hooks`, and I've managed to make it run the tests, but I can't seem to find a way to stop the commit if they tests fail. I'm running the tests with `make test`, which in turn is running `python3.1 foo.py --test`. It seems like I don't get a different exit condition whether the tests pass or fail, but I may be looking in the wrong place.

**Edit:** Is this something uncommon that I want to do here? I would have thought it was a common requirement...

**Edit2:** Just in case people can't be bothered to read the comments, the problem was that `unittest.TextTestRunner` doesn't exit with non-zero status, whether the test suite is successful or not. To catch it, I did:

```
result = runner.run(allTests)
if not result.wasSuccessful():
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Recent questions on SO come up to the top of Google queries pretty quickly; and then drop down in the rankings quickly as well. It's not uncommon to ask a question and 5 minutes later get it as the top Google hit; but in a week, it may be harder for you to find it.

Comment: @Brian Ah, fair enough. I didn't realise Google worked like that.

Comment: Does your `python3.1 foo.py --test` command return a non-zero exit status? Does `make` return a non-zero exit status if you run it manually? And what are the contents of your `pre-commit` hook?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I would check to make sure that each step of the way, your script returns a non-zero exit code on failure. Check to see if your `python3.1 foo.py --test` returns a non-zero exit code if a test fails. Check to make sure your `make test` command returns a non-zero exit code. And finally, check that your `pre-commit` hook itself returns a non-zero exit code on failure.

You can check for a non-zero exit code by adding `|| echo $?` to the end of a command; that will print out the exit code if the command failed.

The following example works for me (I'm redirecting stderr to `/dev/null` to avoid including too much extraneous output here):

```
$ python3.1 test.py 2>/dev/null || echo $?
1
$ make test 2>/dev/null || echo $?
python3.1 test.py
2
$ .git/hooks/pre-commit 2>/dev/null || echo $?
python3.1 test.py
1
```

**`test.py`**:

```
import unittest

class TestFailure(unittest.TestCase):
    def testFail(self):
        assert(False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**`Makefile`**:

```
test:
    python3.1 test.py
```

**`.git/hooks/pre-commit`**:

```
#!/bin/sh
make test || exit 1
```

Note the `|| exit 1`. This isn't necessary if `make test` is the last command in the hook, as the exit status of the last command will be the exit status of the script. But if you have later checks in your `pre-commit` hook, then you need to make sure you exit with an error; otherwise, a successful command at the end of the hook will cause your script to exit with a status of `0`.

Comment: @Brian - Thanks. The problem was that I was running my tests with `unittest.TextTestRunner` which doesn't exit with non-zero status. I had to do `if not result.wasSuccessful(): sys.exit(1)`.

Comment: Another problem here is that the test is running on the working copy of the revision and not the staged. If you always commit all your changes this is not an issue, but if you do partial commits, then your  intermediate commits may not pass the test (See: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412450/git-pre-commit-hook-changed-added-files/3068990#3068990]

Comment: Isn't this: `make test || exit 1` exactly the same as `exec make test`?

Comment: @AdonisK. As I explained, you don't need the `|| exit 1` if this is the last command in your hook. But if you have other commands later on in your hook, then you can't rely on `make test` failing causing the whole hook to fail, and you can't use `exec`. If you do have just one command, yeah, `exec make test` works fine. An alternative to the `|| exit 1` is to use `set -e` to exit on any error.

Answer (score 6):

Could you parse the result of the python test session and make sure to exit your pre-commit hook with a non-zero status?

> The hook should exit with non-zero status after issuing an appropriate message if
>   it wants to stop the commit.

So if your python script does not return the appropriate status for any reason, you need to determine that status directly from the `pre-commit` hook script.
That would ensure the commit does not go forward if the tests failed.
(or you could call from the hook a python wrapper which would call the tests, and ensure a `sys.exit(exit_status)` according to the test results).

Comment: http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/01/28/pexpect-and-inconsistent-exit-status/ could be relevant too here

Comment: Interestingly, in the Git Book, Scott Chacon does a similar thing (parsing the test results), with Ruby: http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html

Comment: Thanks for your help with this one. You were right that the problem was with the appropriate status not being returned. Part of the problem is my noobish shell skills - I haven't quite got the hang yet!

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you don't want to handle manually pre-commit's:
There is nice tool to run tests and syntax checks for Python, Ruby and so on: [github/overcommit](https://github.com/brigade/overcommit)