# git pre-receive hook - getting the newest code

Tags: git, githooks

I am trying to write a `pre-receive hook` for git that will pull the latest version of the code being pushed and run unit tests against it.  My code is below, but when it gets to "git checkout $newrev", I get:

> remote: fatal: reference is not a tree: 188de39ca68e238bcd7ee9842a79397f39a5849e

What do I need to do to get a checkout of the code being pushed before the receive has happened?

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
  echo "Preparing to run unit tests for $newrev"
  TEST_DIR=/opt/git/sommersault-push-tests/sommersault

  # check out this version of the code
  unset GIT_DIR
  echo $refname
  cd $TEST_DIR
  git checkout $newrev

  ...do more stuff...
done
```

Comment: Are you sure you can do that?  How can it checkout code it hasn't received?  I would think you'd need to do a post-receive hook and then have it rollback (reset) if the tests fail.

Comment: I think @wadesworld gave you the correct advice. I could just point this link as a solution for a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087216/commit-in-git-only-if-tests-pass

Comment: Ah, okay.  I was starting out looking at this post - http://codeutopia.net/blog/2011/06/30/how-to-automatically-run-unit-tests-from-a-git-push/ - which seems to imply it's possible to get the code.  (It uses "git archive" rather than "git checkout", though I couldn't get either to work.)  But it makes sense that it wouldn't have access to the code yet.

Comment: Actually, I take that back.  The githooks manpage says `This hook is invoked by git-receive-pack on the remote repository` which indicates it happens after the new content is received.  Note however that it receives a line of input for each ref to be updated.Not sure the cause of the error yet though..

Answer (score 5):

Despite what other people suggested the commit is already received, but it's not written yet.

I would even go as far as saying, that pre-receive hooks are better for deployment that post receive hooks. That why Heroku uses pre-receive hooks to deploy. If you're deployment doesn't go through, you can just reject the commit.

Here's some code that should do the trick for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    echo "Preparing to run unit test for $newrev ... "
    git archive $newrev | tar -x -C /tmp/newrev
    cd /tmp/newrev

    echo "Running unit test for $newrev ... "
    # execute your test suite here

    rc=$?

    cd $GIT_DIR
    rm -rf /tmp/newrev
    if [[ $rc != 0 ]] ; then
        echo "Push rejected: Unit test failed on revision $newrev."
        exit $rc
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this script based on this [howto](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2011/06/30/how-to-automatically-run-unit-tests-from-a-git-push/). Only executes phpunit in selected branches

```
#!/bin/sh

while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    # Only run this script for the dev branch. You can remove this
    # if block if you wish to run it for others as well.
    if [ $refname = "refs/heads/dev" ] ; then
        # Anything echo'd will show up in the console for the person
        # who's doing a push
        echo "Preparing to run phpunit for $newrev ... "

        # Since the repo is bare, we need to put the actual files someplace,
        # so we use the temp dir we chose earlier
        mkdir -p /tmp/$refname
        git archive $newrev | tar -x -C /tmp/$refname

        echo "Running phpunit for $newrev ... "

        # This part is the actual code which is used to run our tests
        # In my case, the phpunit testsuite resides in the tests directory, so go there
        cd /tmp/$refname
        composer install > /dev/null

        # And execute the testsuite, phpunit will send a response error if tests fail
        phpunit --group no-db

        # Clean temp dir
        rm -rf /tmp/$refname
    fi
done

# Everything went OK so we can exit with a zero
exit 0
```

Customize at will...