# Automate app-testing (phantomjs) and merging branches

Tags: javascript, git, unix, testing, phantomjs

I would like to automate testing and merging / deploying my application.

Fist I do testing via *Chimp* and *ESLint*:

```
$ chimp --ddp=http://localhost:3000 --mocha --path=tests --browser=phantomjs
```

and

```
$ eslint ./
```

If these tests are passing completly, I would like to merge the development branch to the master branch:

```
git checkout master
git merge development
```

Is it possible to automate these steps? So if any test is failing, no merge should be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare those steps in a script, testing the exit status for each command before processing the other commands.

For instance, you can have a pre-commit hook calling your javascript commands. See "[Commit in git only if tests pass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2088074/6309)"

---

But this kind of sequence belongs to a Continuous Integration tool ([Travis](https://travis-ci.com/), [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/), [CodeShip](https://codeship.com/) and of course [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/index.html)).

You can there define each command in its own build step: if one fail, the other steps won't execute.

```
.git/hooks/pre-commit:

#!/bin/sh
tests.sh || exit 1
```

With `tests.sh` a script in your `$PATH`, returning an exit status 0 if everything when well.

Comment: But isn't for example *Jenkins* something which is working on the server? And I want to do this local? After testing and merging, I would push the data to the server. Or doesn't this make any sense?

Comment: *You could declare those steps in a script*: What kind of script? And how do I get the status of the test into this script?

Comment: @user3142695 You can use a Jenkins server locally: `java -war jenkins.war`: done.

Comment: I do get this error: `Unrecognized option: -war
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.`

Comment: @user3142695 what java -version returns?

Comment: it returns `1.8.0_102`

Comment: @user3142695 I mean the full complete exact output? Is it a jdk or a jre? What OS are you on?

Comment: @user3142695 Sorry, I just re-read https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins: `java -jar jenkins.jar`

Comment: @user3142695 Then https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project

Comment: @user3142695 Note: I have edited the answer with a simpler approach: a pre-commit hook.