# Doc-tests run from module and command-line and not from pre-commit hook

Tags: python, git, module, doctest, pre-commit

I want to run doc-tests of a Python script as part of a pre-commit hook in Python.

In the file `set_prefix.py`, I have doc-tests in front of functions, which I test before running with:

```py
import doctest
import sys

EXTENSIONS = tuple([".%s" % ending for ending in ["jpg", "heic", "nrw"]])

def is_target_for_renaming(filepath):
    """Returns true if this filepath should be renamed.

    >>> is_target_for_renaming("/Users/username/Pictures/document.other_jpg")
    True
    """

    return filepath.lower().endswith(EXTENSIONS)


def get_failed_tests():
    r = doctest.testmod()
    return r.failed


def main():
    pass


if "__main__" == __name__:

    args = sys.argv
    test_only = 2 <= len(sys.argv) and "test" == sys.argv[1]
    test_failures = get_failed_tests()
    print(test_failures)
    assert 0 == test_failures

    if not test_only:
        main()
```

When I run `python3 set_prefix.py test`, I get the error I expected.

Yet, when I import the module and call the function:

```
import set_prefix

if "__main__" == __name__:

    test_failures = set_prefix.get_failed_tests()
    print(test_failures)
```

I get 0 failures:

```
$ python3 temp.py 
0
```

The reason I want to import the module is to run the tests in a pre-commit hook similar to that added by `flake8`:

```py
#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7
import sys

from flake8.main import git

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        git.hook(
            strict=git.config_for('strict'),
            lazy=git.config_for('lazy'),
        )
    )
```

Why do the doc-tests run when called from the command-line and the script and not when the script is imported? Would `unittest` be a better framework, as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087216/commit-in-git-only-if-tests-pass)?

Answer (score 1):

```
doctest.testmod()
```

runs doctests in `__main__` module and it depends on which script you're actually running.

You can fix this with `m` parameter, but you'll still be forced to add boilerplate code in each module that has doctests. Try this:

```
doctest.testfile("some_module.py")
```

Comment: With code `doctest.testfile("module.py")`, I get many `NameError: name '...' is not defined`, even though the tests run OK when called from the module itself with `python3 module.py`.

Comment: Sounds weird, can you paste a specific NameError?

Comment: I couldn't get the right formatting in a comment. Here's one error: ```File "<doctest set_prefix.py[22]>", line 1, in <module>
        is_target_for_renaming("/Users/username/Pictures/document.other_jpg")
    NameError: name 'is_target_for_renaming' is not defined```
and `set_prefix.py` has
```def is_target_for_renaming(filepath):
    """
    >>> is_target_for_renaming("/Users/username/Pictures/document.other_jpg")
    False
```